# Connect Redis Unix Domain Socket to Django

Tags: ubuntu, django, redis, gunicorn

I have a Django website running via `nginx` under user `www-data` and `gunicorn` under user `myuser` bound at `/run/gunicorn.sock`.

`nginx` works just fine; it acts as a proxy to the `gunicorn` Unix domain socket. I'm not having any problems with `nginx`.

`redis-server` also works just fine. It's domain socket is at `/var/run/redis/redis-server.sock`.

When I enable CACHES in my Django settings file, I get the following exception from `gunicorn`:

```
Error 13 connecting to unix socket: /run/redis/redis-server.sock. Permission denied.
```

Using `ps aux | grep redis`, I find that `/usr/bin/redis-server` is running under the `redis` user, which is totally expected and acceptable, I think. I have added `myuser` to the `redis` group, and restarted the server. I continue to receive that exception.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the two daemons to work together: `gunicorn` and `redis-server`?

Answer (score 0):

I used the default `redis.conf` file at `/etc/redis` and just uncommented their example with regards to the Unix socket.

It had this information:

```
# Unix socket.
#
# Specify the path for the Unix socket that will be used to listen for
# incoming connections. There is no default, so Redis will not listen
# on a unix socket when not specified.
#
unixsocket /var/run/redis/redis-server.sock
unixsocketperm 700
```

I commented out the `unixsocketperm` line and added this one:

```
unixsocketperm 660
```

It worked right away. I'm quite excited and can't wait to see the results of using a cache server.

The reason that it worked is because the middle number in the permissions is 6, and it applies to the group permissions. Prior to my update, the `redis` group had 0 permissions on the socket file. After my update, it now has read and write permissions on the socket file. I read somewhere that socket files do not need execute permission for users, so I removed that permission for security's sake.